# How to find an open ball for a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

I don't understand the process to find the open ball. I understand the definition and I understand that for B(0, delta), I need to substitute x as 0. After this stage, I don't understand where to go next.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: Question]

Comment: The open ball $B(x,\delta)$ is the set of points enclosed by $\{ a : d(x,a) = \delta\}$. Since this case is $\mathbb R$, all you need to do is find the greatest such $a$ and the least such $a$, and then the open ball will be $(a_{min},a_{max})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recall the definition of open ball in a metric space $(X,d)$. $B(x,\delta) = \lbrace y \in X$ such that $d(y,x) <\delta \rbrace$.

Now, you are asked to find the open ball $B(0,1)$. $B(0,1) = \rbrace a \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $d(0,a)<1 \rbrace$. Next step : $d(0,a)=0$ if $a=0$ and else $d(0,a)= 1+\vert a-1 \vert+2\vert a \vert$. So your open ball is the set $\lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace a \in \mathbf{R} : 1+\vert a-1 \vert+2\vert a \vert <1 \rbrace$. Now you still need to solve for that equation, which has I guess no solution!

Hence the open ball $B(0,1) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. (I hope I did not do any mistake)

Comment: Great! Got it, just wanted to check my method was correct which it seems to be. Thank you!